# Start observer ORA-16814

Tags: oracle, observers

The following error was reported when starting the Observer

```
DGMGRL> start observer

Error: ORA-16814: duplicate name specified for observer

Database version 19.11.0

Patterns are: MaxPerformance

GMGRL> show configuration

Configuration - xxx

Protection Mode: MaxPerformance

Members:

xxx - Primary database

xxx - Physical standby database
```

The mode before operation was MaxAvailability, changed to MaxPerformance, and still failed to start observer.

```
ORA-16814: Alternate database AlternateLocation retransmission setting is incorrect
```

I do not know how to check this. How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

DGMGRL> show observer
you'll see something is already running
issue a
DGMGRL> stop observer 'name' (you saw running)

Start the observer